# Memory allocation in java

Tags: java

```
class Someobject
{
  int i=10;
}

public class OtherObject
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Someobject obj=new Someobject();
    System.out.println(obj.i);
  }
}
```

Please tell me in which section of the memory:

1. This entire code will load.
2. Where will `someobject` will be stored.
3. Where will `obj` will be stored
4. Where will `i` be stored.

Thanks every one in advance.

Comment: Please use the formatting to get this code more readable.  Indent the code with four spaces so that is displays nicely.

Comment: To recieve a good answer it would help to put your question in an apropriate way. Please use code blocks for code, and it would also make things easier to read, if you make the numbered list more readable.

Comment: 4 precise and distinct questions, like a homework!

Answer (score 4):

1. The code/classes will load in PermGenSpace
2. The Objects are created in the HEAP
3. The obj reference is stored on the stack
4. `i` is part of the SomeObject instance which lives in the HEAP.